# Does cast to jsonb in PostgreSQL give consistent output for same logical input

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

Does [Postgres `jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSON) give consistent output for same logical input?

```sql
SELECT ('{"def": {"apply_if_file": "go.mod", "package_ecosystem": "gomod", "schedule_interval": "daily"}, "type": "dependabot_configured"}' :: JSONB)

SELECT ('{"def":   {
"package_ecosystem": "gomod", "schedule_interval":         "daily", "apply_if_file": "go.mod"},       "type": "dependabot_configured"}' :: JSONB)

SELECT ('{"type": "dependabot_configured", "def":   {
  "package_ecosystem": "gomod", "schedule_interval":         "daily", "apply_if_file": "go.mod"}       }' :: JSONB)
```

Output:

```
{"def": {"apply_if_file": "go.mod", "package_ecosystem": "gomod", "schedule_interval": "daily"}, "type": "dependabot_configured"}
```

I couldn't find anything about it in the docs, if you claim something, please share proof too.
**Note:** I do not want `input != output`, just the output should be consistent with the same logical input.

Answer (score 0):

[JSON type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html):

> The json and jsonb data types accept almost identical sets of values as input. The major practical difference is one of efficiency. The json data type stores an exact copy of the input text, which processing functions must reparse on each execution; while jsonb data is stored in a decomposed binary format that makes it slightly slower to input due to added conversion overhead, but significantly faster to process, since no reparsing is needed. jsonb also supports indexing, which can be a significant advantage.

> Because the json type stores an exact copy of the input text, it will preserve semantically-insignificant white space between tokens, as well as the order of keys within JSON objects. Also, if a JSON object within the value contains the same key more than once, all the key/value pairs are kept. (The processing functions consider the last value as the operative one.) By contrast, jsonb does not preserve white space, does not preserve the order of object keys, and does not keep duplicate object keys. If duplicate keys are specified in the input, only the last value is kept.

So:

```
select '{"one": 1, "two": 2, "one": 3}'::json;
              json              
--------------------------------
 {"one": 1, "two": 2, "one": 3}

select '{"one": 1, "two": 2, "one": 3}'::json::jsonb;
        jsonb         
----------------------
 {"one": 3, "two": 2}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I'm asking whether every logically same input has the same output, like I modify the input (like whitespaces, ordering, etc), would jsonb still give the same output?

Comment: As the docs say depending on what you do the output would not be the same as the example shows.

Comment: The docs say about key reordering, removing spacing and stuff. Is that consistent for logically same input?

Comment: Do you mean that if you repeatably cast a given static `json` value to `jsonb` the output will always be the same? If so I would yes as the processing is done the same way.

Comment: Not a static json, but a logically same one.

Comment: The more the `json` input deviates from the form of the original the greater the chance  the output will differ in `jsonb`. If you want to get back the same as what you put in then stick to `json`.

Comment: I think the only part of the quote that is relevant is "*jsonb does not preserve white space, does not preserve the order of object keys, and does not keep duplicate object keys*". However, saying "order is not preserved" does not say whether the order is deterministic (or randomised) and whether a deterministic order depends on the order of the input or not. I think what the OP wants to know is whether jsonb values have a **canonical form**, i.e. whether `a::jsonb = b::jsonb` implies `a::jsonb::text = b::jsonb::text`.

Comment: JSON is a way to represent an entity. If we don't have duplicates and json `a` and json `b` are logically equal. By logically equal I mean if we unmarshall it, would we get the same object? so if `a = b` logically, is `a::jsonb::text = b::jsonb::text` ?